# GO - binary.PutUvarint add 1 when the numeric value is above 127

Tags: go

All is in the title.

The GO function `binary.PutUvarint` add 1 when the numeric value is above 127.

I have searched on `stack overflow` and `github` issue and i not found response.

So I post this message to know if somebody can help.

Thank you (Sorry for my bad English)

```golang
b := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)

binary.PutUvarint(b, 129)
fmt.Println(b)
// output
// [129 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(b, 129)
fmt.Println(b)
// output
// [129 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Do you know what "varint" is? It is a variable size encoding, basically it encodes 7 bits at a time, and the high-bit (128) of each byte is used to signal that yet another byte has been encoded. Basically it encoded the value with the bits 12345678 into two bytes with the bits 1234567x 80000000, where x is used to signal the presence of another byte, and was set to 1. Coincidentaly, this is the same value you asked it to encode to begin with so it looks suspicious.

Comment: If you examine the result of calling PutUvarint, you should find that it returns 2, telling you it encoded the input into 2 bytes. The "MaxVarintLen64" is just the maximum length necessary to encode all possible values.

Comment: You can find more information in the [source of varint.go](https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/varint.go).

Comment: I not understand, `PutUvarint` take an uint64, not an int.
So why is put the signed bit.


https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#PutUvarint

Comment: It's not a sign bit, it's that your value required 8 bits to store, so it was split into 2 bytes, that's how **varint** works. It didn't store 8 bytes, it stored 2, `varint` is a variable sized integer encoding technique to save space, small values requires fewer bytes.

Comment: `varint` encodes 7 bits at a time, the lowest 7 bits go into the first byte, the next 7 bits go into the second byte and so on. But only if needed. If the value is less than 128, so it fits into 7 bits, varint encoding will use only 1 byte. The high order bit is reserved in each byte and is set to 1 if there are more bytes that follows.

Comment: 129 requires 8 bits, so the first 7 bits (which result in the value 1) is encoded in the first byte. However, since there needs to be an additional byte to encode the last, 8th byte, the high-order bit of that first byte is set to 1. This, unfortunately, ends up reproducing your original value so it looks a bit odd, but the first byte in the encoded output, 129, is actually the value 1 + a high order bit set to signal the presence of yet another byte. The next byte takes the next 7 bits, which also has the value 1 (the high order bit of your original 129), and then no more bytes.

Comment: The encoding can be thought of like this: `while (value > 0) { byte b = value & 7-bits; value = value shift-right 7-bits; if (value > 0) b = b | high-order-bit-set; output(b); }`

Comment: Make sure you understand what varint is. For instance, you allocated a byte array large enough to hold the maximum possible varint value, which is 10 bytes. But, the encoding of your 129 value only occupies the first 2 bytes, so for instance if you want to write the encoded values to a file or something, you should output 2 bytes, not all 10. The `PutUvarint` function returns the number of bytes it wrote to the array, 2 in your case. If you don't understand this, you'll like output all 10 bytes and this will be wrong.

Comment: I wanted to use `PutUvarint` because it returns the number of bytes.

`LittleEndian.PutUint64` not return the number of bytes.

`n := binary.PutUvarint (b, 129)`
`b = b [:n]`

Comment: But i understand `varint` now, your explications are clear

Comment: PutUint64 always outputs 8 bytes, regardless of the value. 64 bits = 8 bytes. You can construct an 8-byte array and give to it, then you don't need the slice operation either. It's only the "varint" functions that output a varying number of bytes depending on the value output, the non-varint functions outputs a fixed number of bytes relative to the size of the type they handle.

Answer (score 3):

> I have searched on stack overflow and github issue and i not found
>   response.

---

The first place to look is the Go package documentation.

> [Package binary](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/)
>
> import "encoding/binary"
>
> The varint functions encode and decode single integer values using a
>   variable-length encoding; smaller values require fewer bytes. For a
>   specification, see
>   https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding.

Always read the documentation.